# How to get the balance of a wallet using only bash interface?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, bash

I need to get the balance of specifics wallets *only* by using bash terminal tools *without* installing anything new to the OS (An old customized Ubuntu Server)

Any idea how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it by using **blockchain.info** and common bash tools that you already have in your system like **wget**, **grep** and **awk**, **printf** for formatting

For example by using (replace *ADDRESS* with the actual address you want to query):

```
wget -qO- blockchain.info/rawaddr/ADDRESS 2>&1 | grep -Po '"final_balance":\K[0-9]+'
```

And if you want to format the output from satoshi to btc you can use:

```
wget -qO- blockchain.info/rawaddr/ADDRESS 2>&1 | grep -Po '"final_balance":\K[0-9]+' | awk '{s=$1/100000000} END {printf "%0.8f\n", s}'
```